# the difference with bitrate and frame rate with ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I am working on the project that compressed live video with ffmpeg.

I want to know what is the difference between -b 2500k(bitrate) and -r 25 (frame rate)? Is the any relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documented](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options) `-r` tells the encoder to ignore timestamps in the input file and assume a constant frame rate. The frame rate is the number of images per second that are available in the video.

`-b` gives the bitrate for the video. This is the number of bits per second for the video stream.

There is no direct relation between the two numbers.

Comment: Ok do you think that I could use ffmpeg to make real time application ?. In fact I want to take data from webcam by instance to compress it. is it possible to get the best performance with this.

Comment: @user436055: This is a different question. I am not quite sure if you can utilize ffmpeg executable directly for this, but you can use the libav* libraries (like libavcodec, part of ffmpeg project) and build your own application based upon them. PS: If you like my answer, please accept it and maybe upvote it. Thanks.